# How to run a loop in bash to match a string and execute another command ONCE

Tags: linux, bash, loops, while-loop

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish.  I want to run a loop until a string is matched, execute a do command ONCE and move on to the rest of the script?  For example

```
string=`tail /var/myapp/main.log|sort -k5 | awk '{print $4}'`

while [ $string = "failed" ] do
service restart myapp
break
done
echo "blah blah blah as the rest of the script"
echo "on and on"
```

I've tried using until, but I doubt that's the one.  Maybe I'm not using the correct command.  "IF" won't work because I want to run this once a day until it finds what I'm looking for at a specific time, do its thing, do the rest of the script, and be done.  No matter how much I try, it will continue to loop through... forever.  I just want it to do it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for the condition within an infinite loop and break out when it satisfies your criteria:

```
while true; do
  string=$(tail /var/myapp/main.log|sort -k5 | awk '{print $4}')
  [ $string = "failed" ] && break
done
service restart myapp
echo "blah blah blah as the rest of the script"
echo "on and on"
```

Comment: Bingo!  This worked... and now I know why.  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

```sh
while sleep 1
do
  set $(tail /var/myapp/main.log | sort -k5 | awk '{print $4}')
  [ $1 = failed ] || break
done

service restart myapp
```

- loop every second
- every loop check if output equal `failed`
- if not `failed` then break
- rest of script

Comment: The risk here is you may lose the 'failed' message if the log gets quickly cluttered with other messages and `tail` is not looking far enough back.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it did not work.  The loop just broke out and the command was not executed.